# Javascript custom cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor

I try to figure out how to make simple Javascript custom cursor. I find couple Advanced lvl scripts, but that's not what i looking for. I will love to understand most simple way to do it in pure Javascript. I read couple of discussions here and other forums but nothing is working for me.

element.style.cursor = "url('http://bringerp.free.fr/Files/RotMG/cursor.gif'), auto";

Comment: Does your element have a width and height setting? If the element is 0 x 0, it wouldn't work. Also, it needs to have content inside it.

Comment: It might actually be easier to convert your GIF to a .cur file and then use CSS to get your custom cursor working.

Comment: Can i ask sample please?

Comment: Maybe that website image is presenting hotlinking - tried to set as the src for your profile image on this page, but the image failed to load. I don't think there is anything wrong with your javascript.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying is working if you load the external image within a page with the same protocol (http).

Save the image in your web app and load it from your own domain.

I found this page http://www.webpage-maker.com/

open the console and put this in:

```
document.querySelector('#container').style.cursor = "url('http://bringerp.free.fr/Files/RotMG/cursor.gif'), auto";
```

Comment: I try couple of thinks, if i make my own page/localhost or host its working. But what i mean more is make custom cursor for google.com page or similar. Not mine.